# merging multiple dataframes with duplicate rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Relatively new with R for this kind of thing, searched quite a bit and couldn't find much that was helpful.

I have about 150 .csv files with 40,000 - 60,000 rows each and I am trying to merge 3 columns from each into 1 large data frame. I have a small script that extracts the 3 columns of interest ("id", "name" and "value") from each file and merges by "id" and "name" with the larger data frame "MergedData". Here is my code (I'm sure this is a very inefficient way of doing this and that's ok with me for now, but of course I'm open to better options!):

```
file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list){

  if(!exists("MergedData")){
    MergedData <- read.csv(file, skip=5)[ ,c("id", "name", "value")]
    colnames(MergedData) <- c("id", "name", file)
  }

  else if(exists("MergedData")){
    temp_data <- read.csv(file, skip=5)[ ,c("id", "name", "value")]
    colnames(temp_data) <- c("id", "name", file)
    MergedData <- merge(MergedData, temp_data, by=c("id", "name"), all=TRUE)
    rm(temp_data)
  }
}
```

Not every file has the same number of rows, though many rows are common to many files. I don't have an inclusive list of rows, so I included all=TRUE to append new rows that don't yet exist in the MergedData file.

My problem is: many of the files contain 2-4 rows with identical "id" and "name" entries, but different "value" entries. So, when I merge them I end up adding rows for every possible combination, which gets out of hand fast. Most frustrating is that none of these duplicates are of any interest to me whatsoever. Is there a simple way to take the value for the first entry and just ignore any further duplicate entries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, we could stack each file and then cast the resulting data frame from "long" to "wide" format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(reshape2)

df = lapply(file_list, function(file) {
             dat = read_csv(file)
             dat$source.file = file
             return(dat) 
      })
df = bind_rows(df)
df = dcast(df, id + name ~ source.file, value.var="value")
```

In the code above, after reading in each file, we add a new column `source.file` containing the file name (or a modified version thereof).* Then we use `dcast` to cast the data frame from "long" to "wide" format to create a separate column for the `value` from each file, with each new column taking one of the names we just created in `source.file`.

Note also that depending on what you're planning to do with this data frame, you may find it more convenient to keep it in long format (i.e., skip the `dcast` step) for further analysis.

**Addendum:** Dealing with `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length` warning. This happens when you have more than one row with the same `id`, `name` and `source.file`. That means there are multiple `value`s that have to get mapped to the same cell, resulting in aggregation. The default aggregation function is `length` (i.e., a count of the number of values in that cell). The only ways around this that I know of are (a) keep the data in long format, (b) use a different aggregation function (e.g., `mean`), or (c) add an extra `counter` column to differentiate cases with multiple values for the same combination of `id`, `name`, and `source.file`. We demonstrate these below.

First, let's create some fake data:

```
df = data.frame(id=rep(1:2,2), 
                name=rep(c("A","B"), 2), 
                source.file=rep(c("001","002"), each=2),
                value=11:14)

df
```

> ```
>   id name source.file value
> 1  1    A         001    11
> 2  2    B         001    12
> 3  1    A         002    13
> 4  2    B         002    14
> ```

1. **Only one value per combination of `id`, `name` and `source.file`, so `dcast` works as desired.**

   ```
   dcast(df, id + name ~ source.file, value.var="value")
   ```

   > ```
   >   id name 001 002
   > 1  1    A  11  13
   > 2  2    B  12  14
   > ```
2. **Add an additional row with the same `id`, `name` and `source.file`. Since there are now two `value`s getting mapped to a single cell, `dcast` must aggregate. The default aggregation function is to provide a count of the number of values.**

   ```
   df = rbind(df, data.frame(id=1, name="A", source.file="002", value=50))

   dcast(df, id + name ~ source.file, value.var="value")
   ```

   > ```
   > Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
   >
   >   id name 001 002
   > 1  1    A   1   2
   > 2  2    B   1   1
   > ```
3. **Instead, use `mean` as the aggregation function.**

   ```
   dcast(df, id + name ~ source.file, value.var="value", fun.aggregate=mean)
   ```

   > ```
   >   id name 001  002
   > 1  1    A  11 31.5
   > 2  2    B  12 14.0
   > ```
4. **Add a new `counter` column to differentiate cases where there are multiple rows with the same `id`, `name` and `source.file` and include that in `dcast`. This gets us back to a single value per cell, but at the expense of having more than one column for some `source.file`s.**

   ```
   # Add counter column
   df = df %>% group_by(id, name, source.file) %>%
     mutate(counter=1:n())
   ```

   As you can see, the `counter` value only has a value of 1 in cases where there's only one combination of `id`, `name`, and `source.file`, but has values of 1 and 2 for one case where there are two rows with the same `id`, `name`, and `source.file` (rows 3 and 5 below).

   ```
   df
   ```

   > ```
   >      id   name source.file value counter
   > 1     1      A         001    11       1
   > 2     2      B         001    12       1
   > 3     1      A         002    13       1
   > 4     2      B         002    14       1
   > 5     1      A         002    50       2
   > ```

   Now we `dcast` with `counter` included, so we get two columns for `source.file` "002".

   ```
     dcast(df, id + name ~ source.file + counter, value.var="value")
   ```

   > ```
   >   id name 001_1 002_1 002_2
   > 1  1    A    11    13    50
   > 2  2    B    12    14    NA
   > ```

---

<sub>* I'm not sure what your file names look like, so you'll probably need to adjust this create a naming format with a unique file identifier. For example, if your file names follow the pattern "file001.csv", "file002.csv", etc., you could do this: `dat$source.file = paste0("Value", gsub("file([0-9]{3})\\.csv", "\\1", file)`.</sub>

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I explained this well enough. My end goal is a dataframe with the columns "id", "name"  and then 150 columns for the "value" from each of the 150 files. If a file has a value for that "id" "name" combo I want it, if it doesn't an NA is fine. If I stack them, then remove the duplicate "id" "name" entries, won't I remove the associated data?

Comment: See updated code and let me know if that's closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: This is close. I get a few warnings:'> df = bind_rows(df)'
Warning messages:
1: In rbind_all(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In rbind_all(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
'> df = dcast(df, id + name ~ source.file, value.var="value")'
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length.  The resulting dataframe is structured right, but the values are actually counts of entries in each .csv file for that row, not the values themselves.

Comment: The factor warnings just mean that a couple of columns in your original data frames were coded as factors and were coerced to character when you ran `bind_rows` to put them together into a single data frame. If you want those columns to be factors again, just convert them back to factor. Otherwise, you don't need to worry about those warnings. For the second issue, see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a ton for all the help, don't think I would have got this on my own.